# Xcode 4.3 add action for keyboard return key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

How to make the return key on the keyboard to perform an action of (IBAction).

Comment: By reading UIControl's class reference.

Comment: There are tons of questions like this.
Just try to google it. There are very good answers

Comment: There may be tons of questions out there. But this is #1 Google resut for this problem !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well it's simple just add :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self yourButtonName:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement UITextFieldDelegate:

```
@interface yourClass : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Use the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    //do whatever you need here
    //maybe you have several textFields, so first check which one was hit the return key:
    if(textField == outlet_to_your_textField_1){
        //do this
    }
    else if(textField == outlet_to_your_textField_2){
        //do that
    }
    else if ....  blablabla and so on

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i know, but i don't want to rewrite my code, what i want to do is just calling the IBAction, like i have a button and a textfield on a viewController then when the return key pressed it perform the action of the button

Comment: But how do you suppose to make it work without rewriting the code? Actually you have nothing to rewrite, just adding some lines... well maybe quite a bit, but it will take you little time. And I have no idea why do you ask this, and not intending to change parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what How i handle When I press Return Key on iPhone keypad the soft keypad goes back from Text View.
There are three simple ways to handle keypad here

1. Keypad go back when Button clicked.
2. Keypad go back when user click on Return or Done button on keypad.
3. Keypad go back when user Touch on Background screen/view.

> [Handling Soft Keypad in iPhone Tutorial](http://www.rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/handling-soft-keypad-in-iphone-tutorial.html)

hope this will help you.